# Modify XHR response before sending it to client browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xmlhttprequest, saucelabs, browsermob-proxy, selenium-remotedriver

I am new to Webproxy so need some guidance from the experts!
I am running my UI automation tests in Saucelabs using Selenium remote web driver.
When the client browser (in Saucelabs) tries to open a URL "https://abc.xyz.com/login", it makes a XHR request to get JSON file contents from the server.
It then displays the UI elements based on the values in this JSON file.
The JSON file looks like this..

```
{
"Login.Company": "Company",
"Login.Username": "User name",
"Login.Password": "Password"
}
```

I wish to modify the the values of these keys in the XHR response before it gets processed by the client browser so the client will see something like this...

```
{
    "Login.Company": "NewCompany",
    "Login.Username": "NewUser name",
    "Login.Password": "NewPassword"
}
```

My code looks like this...

```
public class WebProxyTests {
Proxy proxy;
BrowserMobProxyServer proxyServer;
private Proxy proxyConfig;
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
void setup() {
    proxyServer = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxyServer.start();
    
    // capture content as a HAR (HTTP Archive)
    // to process when test is complete
    proxyServer.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT,
                                      CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
    proxyServer.newHar();
    
    proxyConfig = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxyServer);
    
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setProxy(proxyConfig);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\webdrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
}

@Test
public void captureTraffic() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("https://abc.xyz.com/login");
    
    final Har httpMessages = proxyServer.getHar();
    for(HarEntry httpMessage : httpMessages.getLog().getEntries()){
        String url = httpMessage.getRequest().getUrl();
        if (url.contains("en-us.json")) {

            // Get the response data from XHR request
            HarContent data = httpMessage.getResponse().getContent();
            if (data != null) {
                System.out.println("DATA>>>>>>>>>" + data.getText());
            }
        }
    }
}

@AfterClass
/***
 * 
 */
void teardown() {
    driver.quit();
    proxyServer.abort();
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I would go about doing this?
Any code examples would really be appreciated?

Comment: You are looking for something specific to be displayed in the browser, regardless of what the server would otherwise display? If you are using Chrome, you can turn on extendedDebugging and use `sauce:intercept` to mock out the response: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Custom+Sauce+Labs+WebDriver+Extensions+for+Network+and+Log+Commands#:~:text=sauce:intercept + response

Comment: I am testing this not just on chrome but on multiple browsers/mobile devices.

Comment: That's good! (except I do not have enough experience with proxies to help with your actual question).